# Determine shape drawn on canvas from stored coordinates in an array

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have startX,startY,endX,endY mousecoordinates using which I draw 3 shapes(a line,ellipse and a rectangle) on canvas.Now I store these coordinates(startX,startY,endX,endY) in a array(for each shape drawn) and draw it again on cleared canvas.Now,the problem is how do I determine from these coordinates stored in the array wheather the shape previously drawn was a circle,a line or a rectangle?

```
function drawLine(toX, toY, context,type) {


            if (type == "line") {
                context.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo((startX), (startY));
                context.lineTo((toX), (toY));
                context.stroke();
            }
            else if (type == "circle") {
                context.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";
                context.beginPath();
                context.moveTo(startX, startY + (toY - startY) / 2);
                context.bezierCurveTo(startX, startY, toX, startY, toX, startY + (toY - startY) / 2);   
                context.bezierCurveTo(toX, toY, startX, toY, startX, startY + (toY - startY) / 2);
                context.closePath();
                context.stroke();
            }
            else if (type == "rect") {
                context.beginPath();
                context.rect(startX, startY, mouseX - startX, mouseY - startY);
                context.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';
                context.stroke();
            }   
    }
```

Now i store these drawn shapes coordinates in a array and draw the same shapes on a cleared canvas by looping through the array of these shapes(with mouse coordinates for each).
Onmouseup event is push my coordinates in an array as follows-

```
     var newLine = new myLine(startX, startY, endX, endY);
            myLines.push(newLine);

   function myLine(xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd) {
        this.xS = xStart;
        this.yS = yStart;
        this.xE = xEnd;
        this.yE = yEnd;
    }
```

Comment: Who calls myLine()? when? who calls drawLine()? when? It's not very clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: DrawLine is being called on mouseup which draws actual shapes on canvas.myLine is also called on mouseup as i wrote above.

Comment: Simply put, you can't. In addition to the co-ordinates, you'll need to store the shape-type. I suggest (a) changing the name of myLine to myShape and (b) adding a field that will hold a string. Also, the canvas has an `arc` method - this is considerably easier (and more accurate) for the computer to compute than a cubic bezier spline.

Comment: @enhzflep how is it possible for me to determine which shape i drawn on mouseup?

Comment: @AkshayJ - The same way you do it now. If you're not up to that part yet, then the typical way is to use the concept of tools, just like any normal paint program uses. First you select the tool you'd like to use - line, rect, circle then you draw it. The code that handles mouse events checks to see which tool is active and performs the appropriate action.

Comment: Embaressingly i myself solved my problem ;) :)

Comment: @AkshayJ - you're welcome, and don't be embarrassed - it's not a bad thing at all. Often times we solve our own problem while working out how to clearly express it so that others may provide solutions. It's a bit ironic, but still okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres how i solved my problem finally :)

```
 var newLine = new myLine(startX, startY, endX, endY,type);
            myLines.push(newLine);

   function myLine(xStart, yStart, xEnd, yEnd,type) {
        this.xS = xStart;
        this.yS = yStart;
        this.xE = xEnd;
        this.yE = yEnd;
        this.type=type
    }
```

And then looped through the array

```
      for (i = 0; i < myLines.length; i++) {

             newxS =  myLines[i].xS ;
                newxE= myLines[i].xE ;

              newyS=  myLines[i].yS ;
                       newyE=  myLines[i].yE  ;

                           ctxtem.strokeStyle = "#FF0000";

                           if (myLines[i].type == "line") {
                               ctxtem.beginPath();
                               ctxtem.moveTo(newxS, newyS);
                               ctxtem.lineTo(newxE, newyE);
                               ctxtem.stroke();


                           }
                           else if (myLines[i].type == "circle") {
                               ctxtem.beginPath();
                               ctxtem.moveTo(newxS, newyS + (newyE - newyS) / 2);
                               ctxtem.bezierCurveTo(newxS, newyS, newxE, newyS, newxE, newyS + (newyE - newyS) / 2);
                               ctxtem.bezierCurveTo(newxE, newyE, newxS, newyE, newxS, newyS + (newyE - newyS) / 2);
                               ctxtem.closePath();
                               ctxtem.stroke();

                           }
                           else if (myLines[i].type == "rect") {
                               ctxtem.beginPath();
                               ctxtem.rect(newxS, newyS, newxE - newxS, newyE - newyS);
                               ctxtem.stroke();
                           }

                ctxtem.save();
}
```